# Online GPX viewer that support 100k+ waypoints

Tags: web-apps, maps, gps

I want to view [this big GPX file](http://wvpoi.batalex.ru/wikivoyage-poi/wikivoyage-listings-en-latest.gpx) without installing any software.

The file is just a long list of 70,000 waypoints like this:

```
[...]
<wpt lat="50.774661" lon="6.084021">
    <name>Aachen Cathedral</name>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="50.775048" lon="6.08282">
    <name>Cathedral Treasury</name>
</wpt>
[...]
```

Requirements:

- Show all waypoints on an Earth map, for instance Google Maps or other
- Support 100,000 waypoints (or at least 70,000)
- Show up in less than 1 minute
- Smooth to scroll/zoom
- Works on Firefox
- Bonus if everything is done browser-side, without sending data to the server

What I tried so far:

- http://www.maplorer.com/view_gpx.html - Takes too long, after 5 minutes it is still loading and freezes Firefox
- http://www.gpsvisualizer.com - Does not show anything
- http://www.mygpsfiles.com/app/ - Says my GPX file contains zero points
- https://maps.google.com/ - It could be good, but the GPX file that can be imported is limited to a size of max 5 MB

The same file loads perfectly in about 10 seconds on OsmAnd an old smartphone.

Comment: Try with this http://www.mygpsfiles.com/en/, I'm note sure it will be able to handle such big gpx files, but worth a try I guess.

Comment: @NicolaBastianello: Tested, it does not manage to display the points. And no issue tracker to report the problem.